# Parsing json object dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object similar to this

```
{
  emp_name:'',
  day1:'',
  day2:'',
  day3:'',
  .....
  dayn:''
}
```

I want to get this value dynamically using javascript and display it in a table. Below is what I am trying to do.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  var row1  = body.insertRow(i);
  var name  = resultset[i].emp_name;
  var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);

  cell1.innerHTML=name;
  cell1.setAttribute('id', 'emp_name');

  for(var j = 1; j < 32; j++)
  {
    var cell2=row1.insertCell(j);
    cell2.innerHTML = resultset[i].day + j;
  }
}
```

But the second cell value is not getting populated. I am getting `NaN`. The problem is because of `day + j`. Can someone say how to approach this?

Comment: Which variable have you equated your json object to? Can you put in ur entire code in a jsbin and show?

Comment: you need `resultset[i]['day'+j];` this called [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood, you want to access the property, which is `day{n}`, right?

If so, you have to change

```
resultset[i].day+j;
```

To

```
resultset[i]['day'+j];
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is identical to `(resultset[i].day) + j` - that means take the value of (nonexistant) `day` property from `resultset[i]`, and add `j` to id. That's why you get a `NaN`.

Whould you should be doing is:

```
 for(var j=1;j<32;j++){
      var cell2=row1.insertCell(j);
        cell2.innerHTML=resultset[i]['day'+j];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If one day, the number of properties or items change, you can loop in your dynamic object without changing your code :

```
for (i = 0, l=resultSet.length; i < l; i++) {
    var row1 = body.insertRow(i);
    var result = resultSet[i];
    var name = result.emp_name;

    var keys = Object.keys(result);
    for (var j = 1, m=keys.length; j < m; j++) {
        var cell2 = row1.insertCell(j);
        cell2.innerHTML = result[keys[j]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged jquery too, I have given the answer using jquery. You can accomplish it using `$.each` function of jquery.

```
$.each(jsonString,function(key,value){
//You can perform your operations here
console.log(key+'=>'+value); 

});
```

Visit here for more info [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)